# Is there a tool to make my CSS3 cross-browser compatible?

Tags: css, cross-browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Painless css3 writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646097/painless-css3-writing)

I've been lazy developing a site, and my hand-crafted CSS contains a lot of lines like

```
border-radius: 10px;
```

without all the variants:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

Is there a tool I can chuck my css files through that will flesh out such lines?

Comment: [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree) reads your CSS and adds the prefixes dynamically with JS where necessary, but doesn't modify your CSS files.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Not a dupe, that person has not written any code yet and is looking to minimize pain. I already have code that I need to fix up.

Comment: @TomMedley: The answers on that post are nearly the same as the ones on this one. Check out thirtydot's solution. It may not be a dupe, but I thought it would be useful to you - sorry if it is not. If you are using PHP, also check out  CSSmin which will do exactly what you want (no need to edit your code) 

http://code.google.com/p/cssmin/

Comment: Hey Tom I'm really curious: how did you discover that you needed `-webkit` and `-moz` prefixes for border-radius? I thought that was no longer necessary, since ages ago. Are there webkit browsers that don't support the standard border radius? What about mozilla, which browsers are you targeting with this, now in almost 2013?

Comment: @WesleyMurch Just something I've always done. If you've got good data that suggests they're no longer necessary I'd love to see it.

Comment: Well you can see which browsers need the prefix here: http://caniuse.com/border-radius I was just wondering which of those you were targeting, since Chrome and Firefox have supported it for a long time, plus those users tend to upgrade their browsers. I don't test any of the other browsers on that list, though.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like:
http://lesscss.org/

It appears to fix the redundant defining over and over.

Comment: I'll consider this for future projects, but it would require rewriting a lot of my css in a 'lessy' way, so it's not so great for my current situation.

Answer (score 0):

For border-radius you can use

http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/downloads/detail?name=border-radius.htc